# Docker "permission denied" error during build

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to install azure cli using python 3.10 in docker on alpine, but I'm getting a

```
 => ERROR [13/16] RUN /$HOME/.pyenv install -v 3.10-dev                                                                                                                                                  0.6s 
------
 > [13/16] RUN /$HOME/.pyenv install -v 3.10-dev:
#17 0.536 /bin/sh: //root/.pyenv: Permission denied
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /$HOME/.pyenv install -v 3.10-dev]: exit code: 126
```

How is build different from runtime? If I run the same commands on a running alpine container, then everything works and gets installed as intended?

```
# Install Azure CLI
RUN apk add libffi-dev ncurses-dev openssl-dev readline-dev tk-dev xz-dev zlib-dev build-base  

# Install pyenv
RUN curl -L https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/raw/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash 

RUN export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv" 
RUN command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH" 
RUN eval "$(pyenv init -)" 
RUN eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)" 

# Restart shell after pyenv install to apply changes
RUN exec $SHELL 

RUN /$HOME/.pyenv install -v 3.10-dev 
RUN pyenv global 3.10-dev 
RUN pip install azure-cli 
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
    apk del libffi-dev ncurses-dev openssl-dev readline-dev tk-dev xz-dev zlib-dev build-base --force-broken-world
```

Sorry if noob question, trying to learn

Comment: It seems like you're missing part of the Dockerfile; what image are you starting `FROM`?  Do you switch to a different `USER`?  Version managers like `pyenv` can be tricky to get running in Docker, and several of the Dockerfile lines you have to set it up actually do nothing; could you build your image `FROM python:3.10` and avoid the `pyenv` setup?

Comment: Thanks, this actually installs the cli, but how do I exit the python env after running FROM?  ```FROM python:3.10
RUN pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
RUN pip install azure-cli --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org```

Comment: What would "exit the Python env" mean?  I'd expect the container to run one thing and for that thing to be a Python process; you shouldn't need to "exit" the isolated environment separately from the container shutdown.